# Client-side WCF ExceptionHandler

Tags: c#, wcf, client-side

Is it possible to handle errors like TimeoutException, EndpointNotFoundException, OperationTimeoutException, etc on **client side** using BehaviorExtension?

I don't want to try-catch-log-restart-connection every time when i'm using WCF proxy.

This code does not working:

### Behavyior:

```
public class EndpointBehavior:IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {


    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        var handler = new WcfErrorHandler();
        clientRuntime.CallbackDispatchRuntime.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(handler);
    }
}
```

### Handler:

```
public class WcfErrorHandler:IErrorHandler
{
    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        Log.Instance.Trace(@"WCF Service Error:", error);
        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        var newEx = new FaultException(
           string.Format(@"Exception caught at WcfErrorHandler{0} Method: {1}{2}Message:{3}",
                        Environment.NewLine, error.TargetSite.Name, Environment.NewLine, error.Message));

        var msgFault = newEx.CreateMessageFault();
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, msgFault, newEx.Action);
    }

}
```

### Extension for app.config

```
public class ExceptionLogBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get 
        {
            return typeof(EndpointBehavior);
        }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new EndpointBehavior();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because `IErrorHandler` is a server-side-only feature.

In your code, it *looks* like you are adding the error handler to client-side requests, but actually that's not the case. That's because `clientRuntime.CallbackDispatchRuntime` is a server-like entity that lives in the client and is used to receive messages from the real server in [duplex operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services).

Regarding your main question about client-side exception handling, the best I can recommend is `IClientMessageInspector`. Here's some code to help you get started:

```cs
public sealed class LoggingEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new LoggingInspector());
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
}

public sealed class LoggingInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BeforeSendRequest");
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AfterReceiveReply");
    }
}
```

However, note that `IClientMessageInspector` has a drawback. Its `AfterReceiveReply` method is called on successful and faulty replies from the server, but **is not called** when there isn't any reply at all, e.g. on `TimeoutException`, `EndpointNotFoundException`, etc.